# Why ListView.builder is suitable for large (or infinite) number of children and ListView.separated isn't?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and, currently build an app which has a list with a series of different item types.

Since the amount of item is unknown and, due to its variety, the `ListView.builder` constructor seemed the best option for me at the time, since I could create a `Widget` for each item and return them properly on `itemBuilder` in a vey clean manner. However, I didn't find a nice way to implement dividers with `ListView.builder` and ended up changing to `ListView.separated`. The change was effortless and only required passing a new `separatorBuilder` parameter.

The problem is, Flutter docs state that `ListView.separated` "*is appropriate for list views with a fixed number of children*".

My questions are:

1. Why `ListView.separated` is not suitable for a large number of items while `ListView.builder` is?
2. Is there any performance issues with `ListView.separated` for a high quantity of items?
3. Would there be a better way to implement dividers that depends on items' types using `ListView.builder` that wouldn't involve me wrapping my `Widgets` in a `Padding` or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions:

## 1. Why ListView.separated is not suitable for a large number of items while ListView.builder is?

The [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html) also say:

> This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large number of item and separator children because the builders are only called for the children that are actually visible.

So, according to the page you read and the page I quoted here, in both, the builder is called only once for each item in the list. No matter the size of the list. It only mentions, the list should be of fixed size, not small size. It's due to a range exception that could occur.

## 2. Is there any performance issues with ListView.separated for a high quantity of items?

As stated before, the performance isn't much different, since the builder is called the same amount of time.

## 3. Would there be a better way to implement dividers that depends on items' types using ListView.builder that wouldn't involve me wrapping my Widgets in a Padding or something like that?

There is no need to, since `ListView.separated` is perfect for your case.

Answer (score 1):

To see the difference between each one go visit [ListView Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

And sure, you can create Forms with `ListView.builder()`, but I've found some problems trying it.

1. I can't put it into any `ListView()`, either `Column()`, to put them if there's any more items than just the `Form()`.
2. I couldn't even add a Button at the of the `ListView.builder()` even using a conditional to put it when the last index is reached. Because of that, you have to use `textInputAction: TextInputAction.done` to perform some kind of action at `onFieldSubmitted:`
3. The best way to get the Fields data I've found was to add them all into an `array` when the `onSaved:`method is called, and I don't think that's a good way to go (maybe it is).

With that being said, that's what I used to make it work:

```
body: Form(
    key: _key,
    child: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            validator: (text) {
              if (text.isEmpty) {
                return "The text is empty";
              }
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (text) {
              _onSaved();
            },
            onSaved: (text) {
              form.add(text);
            },
          );             
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),

void _onSaved() {
  if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
    _key.currentState.save();
    print(form);
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
I/flutter ( 7106): [fjjxjx, hxjxjcj, jxjxjfj, jfjfj, jxjxj]
```